Again EAV - flexible DB design to allow user added properties
What is the problem? I want to make a material database. The User should be able to create different material types and create materials of this type. But different material types have different material properties. And new materials may have new properties.
Example:
Material 1: Oil

Viscosity
Density
Melting Point

Material 2: Metal

Density
Melting Point
Ductility

Material 3: cement

Finess of cement
Soundness of cement
Strength
Setting time
Heat of Hydration

Material X: xxxxx
You see that different materialtypes has sometimes same or different properties. Some materialtypes have few properties others many. The properties may be of complete different data types, like STRING, FLOAT, INT, etc.
Adding a new materialtype should not result in a "development of new code" and an admin to create / change the DB / Table Schema.
So I need an approach where an User can create a new material type in the application, can create new properties in the application and create the relationship between both, meaning he defines (=relationship) which properties a materialtype has.
When then creating material, he selects the material type of the material and fills out only the properties the material has.
Under the DB normalization rules, materialtype, properties and material would be 3 different tables. Also there would be relationtables which create the relations between the tables and the values of the properties.
What would be the best approach? My ideas:

EAV with all the problems associated, values are stored in STRING format, whatever they are
EAV with the difference, that in the Table for the main DATA Types like STRING, FLOAT, BOOLEAN, BLOB I will have a separate column, the Data Type column defines in which column the data will be stored
Each datatype will create a OWN Table (this customtable's name will be stored in a column/field of the Materialtype table). The created table will have fields/columns with the right datatype of each property [maybe many different tables]

Are there other options and what would you recommend?

Most of these ideas proceed from a wrong assumption that "users" - what this often really means is people unskilled in the design of information systems, often unsuited to that work, and whose jobs do not primarily consist of such responsibilities - are capable of doing what is otherwise considered an expert job, if only a nice front end is put on these otherwise fussy technologies.
The reality is that when "users" are given arbitrary powers to create properties, you will simply end up with a jumble of properties, because you are ceding the task to an array of people, none of whom are particularly competent to think about how a system of properties should be organised, and none of whom are performing the role of a supervisor and overall decision-maker about this system.
Moreover, when change is required to get the jumble back into shape, developers (or those in allied trades, like analysts) will simply be called back to structure that jumble and to fix the mess in the existing data, so you haven't really got rid of the "admin" involvement.
The main issue with EAV is not the minutiae of approaches which you are asking about - all of which could be workable, when considered in the abstract. The issue with EAV is more about a wide variety of wrong underlying assumptions that make it seem attractive.
This includes wrong assumptions about the comparative roles/capabilities of developers and users as I've mentioned above.
And it includes wrong assumptions about the comparative flexibility of EAV against its development overheads and ongoing maintenance costs, compared to just having a developer on-hand to make hard-coded changes when necessary to a conventionally-structured application.
Even in applications where EAV has not led to some kind of crisis (most likely in the simplest and most low-volume applications with the fewest concurrent users), I'm not sure any developer will agree that it ever saves a minute of labour for the developer - something which you seem to identify as a key perceived advantage.
